# Unable to view EKS cluster created from terraform resources

Tags: networking, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

We are creating an EKS cluster using terraform resources: `aws_eks_cluster` and  `aws_eks_node_group`.
After applying these resources, when we query for the nodes using `kubectl`, we are able to see the nodes in the cluster with all the auto scaling settings. We are even able to fetch the `kubeconfig` file of this cluster in out bastion instance. But we are not able to view this cluster from the AWS console under the EKS service. Is this an expected behavior? Below is our code:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name            = "${var.eks_cluster_name}"
  role_arn        = "${var.iam_role_master}"
  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = ["${var.sg-eks-master}"]
    subnet_ids = ["${var.subnet_private1}", "${var.subnet_private2}"]
    endpoint_private_access= true
    endpoint_public_access = true
        public_access_cidrs = ["<ip_range>"]
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
  cluster_name    = "${var.eks_cluster_name}"
  node_group_name = "ng-${var.eks_cluster_name}"
  node_role_arn   = "${var.iam_role_node}"
  subnet_ids      = ["${var.subnet_private1}", "${var.subnet_private2}"]
  ami_type = "${var.image_id}"
  instance_types = "${var.instance_type}"

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 4
    min_size     = 2
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking in the correct account and region?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to see the rest of the resources that I have created. Only the cluster isnt visible.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was just a permissions issue. The user was not having view access to EKS clusters. But the problem was that no warning/error message was shown in the console saying that this is a role issue. Only when we checked the roles for the user, we figured this out.